# getting to grips with Quickbooks Hello World app, all working ok but I have what I think is an easy question

Tags: quickbooks-online

in application.properties I need to set the OAuth2 keys...

```
OAuth2AppClientId=AB............................AN

OAuth2AppClientSecret=br................................u8

OAuth2AppRedirectUri=http://localhost:8085/oauth2redirect
```

Initially I put the keys in "" quotes assuming they should be treated as a string but to get it working I had to remove them. Can someone explain what's happening with

```
OAuth2AppClientId=AB............................AN when I build the app
```

and how do I find out more about OAuth2AppClientId?

Answer (score 0):

A *Google search* is probably the place to start here. Here's a great resource about what a `Client ID` and `Client Secret` are:

- https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/

I quote:

- `The client_id is a public identifier for apps.`
- `The client_secret is a secret known only to the application and the authorization server.`

Intuit also has *a ton* of documentation on OAuth2, and how to implement it. You should read it:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0

In summary, the `Client ID` is how Intuit identifies that it's *your app* trying to connect to QuickBooks. Nothing is "happening" to the string when you build/compile the app - it's just normal `string`. But when your app authenticates against QuickBooks Online, your app sends the `Client ID` to QuickBooks so that QuickBooks knows it's your app trying to authorize a connection to QuickBooks, and not some other app.

Comment: thanks Keith, will take a look at the links. Do you know why build fails when I use quotes e.g. OAuth2AppClientId="AB............................AN"

Comment: Because the syntax of `application.properties` file says that quotes are _part of the string_ and not a delimiter. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how to code is loading this, it is only a property being used inside the application

**OAuth2PlatformClientFactory**

```
@Service
@PropertySource(value="classpath:/application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound=true)
public class OAuth2PlatformClientFactory {

    @Autowired
    org.springframework.core.env.Environment env;

    OAuth2PlatformClient client;
    OAuth2Config oauth2Config;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // intitialize a single thread executor, this will ensure only one thread processes the queue
        oauth2Config = new OAuth2Config.OAuth2ConfigBuilder(env.getProperty("OAuth2AppClientId"), env.getProperty("OAuth2AppClientSecret")) //set client id, secret
                .callDiscoveryAPI(Environment.SANDBOX) // call discovery API to populate urls
                .buildConfig();
        client  = new OAuth2PlatformClient(oauth2Config);
    }


    public OAuth2PlatformClient getOAuth2PlatformClient()  {
        return client;
    }

    public OAuth2Config getOAuth2Config()  {
        return oauth2Config;
    }

    public String getPropertyValue(String propertyName) {
        return env.getProperty(propertyName);
    }

}
```

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/OAuth2-JavaWithSDK/blob/master/src/main/java/com/intuit/developer/sampleapp/oauth2/client/OAuth2PlatformClientFactory.java